# Looking for an old fantasy short story, and the anthology it was in

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It is a short story in an anthology (fantasy/science fiction) about a girl who lived in a village by the sea, who rescued a man who had been in a shipwreck, of a ship used by invaders. He had the ability to find his way anywhere on the ocean. The people of the village tested him and he found the girl's brother, stranded on a small island. The girl was dreamy, and saw horses in the surf. It ends with the man wrecking an invader ship, and the village in the process, and she joins him on a horse from the sea, to escape.

Comment: Sounds familiar. Could the anthology have been one of the late-teen numbered (17, 18, 19) Year's Best New Science Fiction series, edited by Gardiner Dozois?